# Type conversion issue in nested case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following (simplified and obfuscated) query appears to (in my
 mind) return a varchar type from each possible return branch in the
 nested case expression. I went to the trouble of casting the first
 two possible return branches to varchar to ensure their congruence
 with the last two possible return types as represented in the last
 (most deeply nested) case statement which returns strings. However,
 when run, it complains about trying to convert the string 'foo' to an
 int. Everything worked fine until I added that bottommost, most
 deeply nested, case statement that always returs strings (and indeed,
 before I added that, there was no need for any conversion of dates
 since dates were all that could ever be returned).  QUESTION: Any
 idea why sql server is trying to convert the 'foo' string (and
 probably 'bar ...' string if it could get that far) into an int? More
 importantly, any ideas on a solution to solve the casting/conversion
 issue?  Thanks in advance.

```
select case
         when t1.flubbitz - t1.dubbitz <= 0
         then 
           case
             when (select min(t3.[duedate])
                   from blatz t3  
                     inner join dort t4 on t3.anumerickey = t4.anumerickey 
                   where t4.[somenumbercol] = t2.somenumbercol
                     and t4.somecode = '01'
                       and t3.duedate > getdate()) is not null
             then (select left(convert(varchar, (select min(t3.[duedate])
                   from blatz t3  
                     inner join dort t4 on t3.anumerickey = t4.anumerickey 
                   where t4.[somenumbercol] = t2.somenumbercol
                     and t4.somecode = '01'
                       and t3.duedate > getdate()), 101), 10))
             else 
               case 
                 when (select min(t0.[duedate])
                       from sabtz t0  
                             inner join quux t1 on t0.anumerickey = t1.anumerickey 
                       where t0.somenumbercol = t2.somenumbercol
                         and t0.duedate > getdate()) is not null
                 then (select left(convert(varchar, (select min(t0.[duedate])
                       from sabtz t0  
                             inner join quux t1 on t0.anumerickey = t1.anumerickey 
                       where t0.somenumbercol = t2.somenumbercol
                         and t0.duedate > getdate()), 101), 10))
                     else 
                   case
                     when t2.somenumbercol like 'blub%' then 'foo'
                     when t2.somenumbercol like 'batz%' then 'bar ' + left(convert(varchar, getdate(), 101), 10) 
                   end    
               end 
           end       
         else (select null) 
       end as [Foobar]

from yyy t1 
     inner join xxx t2 on t1.somenumbercol = t2.somenumbercol

where ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the "(SELECT NULL)".

In the examples below, "(SELECT NULL)" throws the error and "NULL" does not.  The "()" casts the NULL as an INT.

```
SELECT CASE -- error
WHEN 3 < 2 THEN 'Hello'
ELSE (SELECT NULL)
END
UNION
SELECT 'Goodbye'

SELECT CASE -- works
WHEN 3 < 2 THEN 'Hello'
ELSE NULL
END
UNION
SELECT 'Goodbye'

SELECT CASE -- works
WHEN 3 < 2 THEN 'Hello'
ELSE CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR)
END
UNION
SELECT 'Goodbye'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet figured out why this occurs sometimes.  According to the T-SQL documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), CASE "Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression."

It occurs to me just now that CASE may default to an INT in the absence of an ELSE condition.  (All your other CASE statements have ELSE conditions.) For the sake of intellectual curiosity, you could add an ELSE '' within your CASE statement and see if the compiler properly interprets the entire statement as a char.  But I digress...

The important thing is, of course, to make the query work, which you can do by wrapping the entire CASE statement in a CAST, like this:

```
CAST(case
    when t2.somenumbercol like 'blub%' then 'foo'
    when t2.somenumbercol like 'batz%' then 'bar ' + left(convert(varchar, getdate(), 101), 10) 
end AS nvarchar(15))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Michael for replying. Appreciated. Even though I have the answer (from above), I will also investigate the parity of elses which you mentioned.

Comment: Cool, man.  Glad you asked the question, because I didn't know about the () = int thing, either.